# How to restore focus on a widget after hidding then showing the parent widget?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside

I'm creating a launcher application (like Spotlight/Albert/Gnome-Do). I'm using Python 2.7 and Pyside. Made and used on Windows 10.

It is running in the background and listening to a shortcut with the *keyboard* (`pip install keyboard`). When the shortcut is called, a QObject signal calls the show method of my main widget.

My issue is that when the main widget gets hidden by pressing escape or return, next time the widget is shown, the focus will be in the QlineEdit and the user will be able to type its query straight away.

But when the widget is hidden by clicking outside widget (handled by filtering the QEvent WindowDeactivate), the focus won't be on my QLineEdit at next call, which ruins the user experience.

I've tried playing with activateWindow() or raise_(), but it doesn't change anything.

Heree here a simplified example code that shows my problem:

```py
import sys
import keyboard
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

SHORTCUT = 'Ctrl+space'


class ShortcutThread(QObject):
    signal = Signal()


class Launcher(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Launcher, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.Popup)
        self.resize(500, 50)
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout_ = QHBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout_)
        self.search = QLineEdit()
        self.layout_.addWidget(self.search)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        # Hide dialog when losing focus
        if event.type() == QEvent.WindowDeactivate:
            self.hide()
        return super(Launcher, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        # Hide dialog when pressing escape or return
        if e.key() in [Qt.Key_Escape, Qt.Key_Return]:
            self.hide()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

    launcher = Launcher()

    shortcut = ShortcutThread()
    shortcut.signal.connect(launcher.show)

    keyboard.add_hotkey(SHORTCUT, shortcut.signal.emit, args=[])

    launcher.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I call the shortcut (Ctrl+Space here) and click elsewhere, next time I'll call the shortcut, the focus won't be set to the QLineEdit widget.

When the launcher is hidden by hitting return or escape, it does work as expected.

Comment: I am analyzing the problem and it is only generated in python2, in python3 it works correctly for me

Comment: Good point, I should have checked that to begin with. Unfortunately, the tool is meant for CGI industry, where Python 2.7 is still the standard (I know...). So I'll keep digging